# Writing an if statement in tensorflow and comparing the values of two tensors

Tags: if-statement, boolean, tensorflow

I have the condition:

```
if tf.shape(n_spec)[0] < tf.shape(s_spec)[0]:
    n_spec = tf.concat(0, [tf.zeros([empty_cols, n_spec.get_shape()[1]], tf.int32), n_spec])
```

where n_spec and s_spec are two tensors (2d arrays) and I want to perform that concatenation if one is smaller than the other in the 0 dimension. When I try this, tensorflow throws an error:

```
TypeError: Using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed. Use `if t is not None:` instead of `if t:` to test if a tensor is defined, and use TensorFlow ops such as tf.cond to execute subgraphs conditioned on the value of a tensor.
```

How can I reformulate the above?

Answer (score 0):

From your code, it seems like the shape of `n_spec` is known statically (since you are using `n_spec.get_shape()`). In this case, you can simply do the following :

```
if n_spec.get_shape()[0] < s_spec.get_shape()[0]:
  n_spec = tf.concat(0, [tf.zeros([empty_cols, n_spec.get_shape()[1]], tf.int32), n_spec])
```